# Only variables should be passed by reference.. Need some help :) (PHP)

Tags: php

Here is what it's saying:

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\login\register.php on line 20

In line 20, I have

```
$stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store value of hash in a variable and then pass it.

```
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
```

For more reference: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score 1):

Avoid function call in `Statement#bindParam`, its return value cannot be passed as reference.

Try to separate the function call:

`$pwd = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $pwd);`

More info on passing values by reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of bindParam is a variable reference. Since a function return cannot be referenced, it fails to strictly meet the needs of the bindParam parameter.

```
   $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
   $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first Store the value of password_hash($_POST['password'] in a variable ($pwd) and then pass it

```
$pwd = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $pwd);
```

Yes, it works

It is part of PHP Regiter, Login, Logout script available at following link: https://github.com/thedevdojo/php-login-script