# not redirecting to the reference page

Tags: php

```
class User{
protected $pdo;
function __construct($pdo){
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
}
public function checkInput($var){
    $var = htmlspecialchars($var);
    $var = trim($var);
    $var = stripcslashes($var);
    return $var;
}
```

1. and here it show Only variables should be passed by reference

   ```
   public function login ($email, $password){
   $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT 'user_id' FROM 'users' WHERE 'email' = :email AND 'password' = :password");
   $stmt ->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $stmt ->bindParam(":password", md5($password), PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $stmt ->execute();

   $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
   $count = $stmt->rowCount();
   ```
2. here the redirecting page not reloads just shows the html error

   ```
   if ($count > 0) {
       $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user ->user_id;
       header('Location: home.php');
   }else{
       return false;
   }
   ```

   }
   }

Comment: Which "html error"? (Also, md5 is unsuitable for password hashing – see http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php and  [`password_hash`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php))

Comment: after changing the md5 to hash it shows the error

Comment: Specifically what error? Put the contents of the error here.

Comment: Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\core\classes\user.php on line 18

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42246668/only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference-need-some-help-php

Comment: after using the same function the error not shows but now it not matches the value of db and shows the error of condition and not redirects to referal page

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that your bind_params second parameter are reference.
In strict standard this should be variables so this code

```
$stmt ->bindParam(":password", md5($password), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Should be

```
 $hashed_pass =  md5($password);
 $stmt ->bindParam(":password", $hashed_pass , PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

The same goes if you use password_hash instead of md5

You may read this question for more information
[Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-)

Comment: now sql  not runs to match the data and shows the error

Comment: now it not connects the databse and shows the error how to fix it